# In a header, how to use some declarations from another header without exposing everything in it?

Tags: c++, header

In my header, I use a templated constexpr to translate typenames to `MPI_Datatype`s:

```
// MyHeader.h

#include <mpi.h> // declares MPI_Datatype and MPI_CHAR

template<typename T>
constexpr MPI_Datatype Type2MPI() {
    if (std::is_same<T, char>::value) {
        return MPI_CHAR;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This exposes `mpi.h` when included. I don't want that.

Normally, I would simply declare the `Type2MPI` function in the header and define it in a source file, which includes `mpi.h`.
However, that's not possible because it is templated.

Is there any way to use values from `mpi.h` without openly including it in its entirety in my header?

Copy-pasting values from `mpi.h` is not possible.

What I hope for might be something like this:

```
// MyHeader.h

from <mpi.h> use MPI_Datatype;
from <mpi.h> use MPI_CHAR;

// ...
```

---

## Example use case

In MyHeader.h:

```
private:

    template<typename T>
    constexpr MPI_Datatype Type2Mpi() { ... }

    void SendImpl(const void* p, MPI_Datatype type);

public:
    template<typename T>
    void Send(const T& data) {
        SendImpl (&data, Type2Mpi<T>());
    }
```

Note that this currently requires including mpi.h to get access to `MPI_Datatype`.

---

## What I ended up doing

As I could not get the constexpr to work, I did it the old way.

Header (does not include mpi.h):

```
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Send(const T& data);
}
```

cpp:

```
#include <mpi.h>

template<>
void Send(const char& data) {
    SendImpl (&data, MPI_CHAR);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Even if it wasn't templated, you'd still need the definition of the type `MPI_Datatype` (the type of the return value), which I assume is in `mpi.h`. So as long as you use such a type in your interface, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: @wohlstad Indeed. I'm fine with exposing these. However, I don't want to expose the other 1000 declarations from mpi.h :)

Comment: The minimum you need is the definition of `MPI_DataType` and the definition of the templated `Type2MPI()`.   Extract those into a separate header, which is `#include`d by both `mpi.h` and `MyHeader.h`.   There will need to be suitable include guards in that header if both `mpi.h` and `MyHeader.h` are included anywhere (e.g. by a source file, or another header).

Comment: you can define an `inline constexpr` constant in your header file, if needed put it in a seperate constants header file.

Comment: _"I don't want to expose the other 1000 declarations from mpi.h"_ - Why? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Peter AFAIK, this wouldn't be portable. Different MPI implementations define `MPI_Datatype` differently. For instance, in OpenMPI, it is defined as a type alias for a pointer to a proprietary type `struct ompi_datatype_t*`: https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/main/ompi/include/mpi.h.in#L448.

Comment: You _could_ forward declare MPI_Datatype and MPI_CHAR, then return a pointer from the function. Then you could remove `#include <mpi.h>` from the header file and place it in the .cpp file instead. I wouldn't recommend doing that though. You also wouldn't be able to template the function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to control which code uses MPI. Having a single point of access, i.e. a single point that includes its header, makes my life easier when debugging this monster.

Comment: Any other file can still `#include <mpi.h>` so I don't see what you'd gain. Anyway, you can hide `MPI_Datatype` behind your own type and map between `MAFU_Datatype` and `MPI_Datatype` internally in the implementation if you'd like.

Comment: If some code doesn't use MPI, why would that code need to include the declaration of `Type2MPI()`?

Comment: @DanielLangr   If *that* (using multiple distinct implementations of mpi, and unable to modify `mpi.h`) is a constraint, then this question as asked has no maintainable solution.   The minimum requirement to be able to use types from a header is to be able to replicate the necessary type definitions in a separate header, and somehow prevent a situation of defining those types differently in different parts of the program.]

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, but that is easy to detect. I just want to avoid mistakes by using something out of sync with the rest of the system. -- I don't know how to replace the type. Maybe that could be an answer?

Comment: @Evg It does not use it directly, but indirectly. All calls to the underlying MPI lib should go through a well-defined gateway.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Could you add an answer with inline constexpr?

Comment: What does "indirectly" mean? Could you add an example of `cpp` file that needs `Type2MPI()` but doesn't need to include `mpi.h`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one MPI to use at the same time in the runtime? From the comments you made, you can contain the header file below or something like it in the .cpp files which use <mpi.h>, using MY_CHAR in the .cpp files. The header file is just a switch, you make change in it to enable/disable all things about MPI.

```
// single_point.h

#define __USE_MPI__ // When not using <mpi.h>, change __USE_MPI__ to __USE_MPI__xx.

#ifdef __USE_MPI__
#include <mpi.h>
#define MY_CHAR MPI_CHAR
#else
#define MY_CHAR char
#endif
```